# Arduino Due DAC pins with 0V

Tags: arduino-due, digital-analog-conversion

I know the DACs on the Arduino Due only allow for a range of output voltages from 1/6*Vdd to 5/6*Vdd (see [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=154965.0)). This suits my needs, for the most part.

My question is if it is possible to have 0V on the DAC pins by, for example, switching the DACs of completely, or using them as normal digital out pins. I'd like to do this without the need for any external hardware or circuitry.

I googled for solutions but found none.

Answer (score 0):

The DAC is port B15 and B16 so yes, it is possible to disable the DAC and use those pins as normal GPIO pins. Not sure how you would do it though, if the Arduino definitions have those pins set up for GPIO or not (away from my computer at the moment).

Comment: It's apparently not possible. This answer covers the topic very precisely. https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/25843/16623